# InputStream.read() blocking (jamming) execution

Tags: java

I've been writing basic bit level encryption code, and I'm pretty sure that the algorithm is correct.. But I can't test it. When I run the code, the first loop (Using `System.in.read()` ) jams the code. When I send the `EOF` signal via the terminal, the code progresses no further - I've checked with some primitive `print` statements on the next line.

As I understand, sending the `EOF` should have `read()` return `-1`, exiting the loop.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

```
public class BitLevel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
    ArrayList<Integer> key = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter key: ");
    System.out.flush();
    int c = System.in.read();
    while (c != -1) {
        key.add((Integer) c);
        c = System.in.read();
    }
    c = input.read();
    while (c != -1) {
        output.write(c ^ key.get(i).intValue());
        output.flush();
        i++;
        i = i % key.size();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should probably do the reading in the standard way, with a `Scanner` etc.

Comment: Thanks, Kayaman. I did miss the "c = " Oddly, the bug persists after I fixed that, though.

Comment: Why are you even trying to read this way? It's just wrong. You'll find a decent example of reading input from any basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop will never end because "c" doesn't get changed inside of it. I think you meant to also call the `c = input.read();` inside the loop, at its end.

Also, BTW, you should close the streams after you are done with them.

Answer (score 0):

The call on `System.in.read()` reads exactly one byte. You might want to use the `Scanner` but to fix your issue look at this

```
 int c = System.in.read();
 while (c != -1) {
        key.add((Integer) c);
        System.in.read();
    }
```

You read `c` once and never change it in the while loop by reading another one. Change it to

```
 int c = System.in.read();
 while (c != -1) {
        key.add((Integer) c);
        c = System.in.read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It *did* return -1, but you forgot to store the return value so you could test it.